# Python and pandas. Check if values in columns "name" and "last_name" are in "email" column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

In the following pandas df, How can I check if the name and last names are included in the email column?

Ex df:

```
header:   f_name    l_name    email
values    Peter     Gabriel   peter.gabriel@email.com
```

How can I check if the email `peter.gabriel` corresponds with the `f_name` and `l_name` values?

How can I print the rows that are wrong?

I'm reading the information from a `.csv` file into a dataframe as

```
contacts = pd.read_csv('contacts.csv')
contacts_df = pd.DataFrame(contacts)
```

Comment: Are all e-mails separated by `.`? Or do you have `peter_gabriel@...`, `peter-gabriel`, `petergabriel@...`?

Comment: Why should an email address include first and last names? Most don't. But in any case, if you can get the f_name and the l_name, all you have to do is convert them to lower case, concatenate them with a period in between and then see if that is a substring of the email field. Then do it for every row.

Comment: Hi! The csv is comma separated and there is a dot between name.lastname. I needed to work on this file to upload accounts to a service. For some reason some rows had the wrong email. Ex. rows 6 and 7 had switched emails. So I was thinking this could be faster that checking the almost 1000 rows visually. Thanks for loking at it. /Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['new'] = df2['f_name'].str.lower()+'.'+df2['l_name'].str.lower()
print(df.apply(lambda x: x['new'] in x['email'], axis=1))
```

This will give you a series of Trues and Falses that will tell you whether the email address is appropriate or no.

Comment: Hi! This does the trick. Thanks! I just discovered a little thing... Here in Sweden we have names like Björn Borg . The ö character is a normal 'o' in the email which results in a 'False'. Any way to fix this? Thank you for your time!

Comment: There's no easy way to do that. You have to find the appropriate ASCII codes and convert them. On that note tho, if this was helpful, make sure to hit that checkmark! Next to the arrows

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with some idea. Please try it :)

First I have a function which is checking your condition:

```
def check(row):
    return f"{row['f_name'].lower()}.{row['l_name'].lower()}" in row['email']
```

From this point you just have to apply this using:

```
df['is_correct'] = df.apply(check, axis=1)
```

**Output:**

When there is something wrong you will get something like this:

```
email   f_name  l_name  is_correct
0   dawid.sielski@sth.com   Dawidd  Sielski False # double 'd' at the end of the name
```

and when everything is ok it will look something like this:

```
    email   f_name  l_name  is_correct
0   dawid.sielski@sth.com   Dawid   Sielski True
```

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, imagine my name was William Iam, and my email was william@bnl.gov. Your program will ok this. On the other hand, if my name was John Smith, and my email was John.Smith@gmail.com, your program will reject this.